# Spacing Issue with CSS

Tags: html, css

In my local server the product boxes fill the full width of the page as they are set to a complete value of 100%. And the borders are showing nicely..

[image]

But on my live test site its not filling 100% and leaving a gap on the far right. aswell as the borders between the products disappearing...
It seems that the hover effect is sitting at the right width as it is overflowing on the right of the product image.(attached image)

Live site here: http://pagedev.co.uk/hoppings/products/

[image]

This is the CSS for each product box:

```
.grid-wrapper {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    margin:0px auto;
}

.grid-wrapper img{
    width:99.8%;
    height:auto;
}

.grid-item {
    width:20%;
    margin-right:-6px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    border:1px solid #cfd0d1;
    border-top:0px solid #cfd0d1;   
    background-color:#ffffff;

    @media #{$l-desktop} {
        width:25%;
        margin-right:-6px;
    }

    @media #{$desktop} {
        width:33.2%;
        margin-right:-5px;
    }

    @media #{$mobile} {
        width:50%;
        margin-right:-5px;
    }
}



.image-hovers {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    position:relative;
}

.product-hover{
    position:absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0px;
    margin:0 auto; left:0px;
    z-index:100;


    background-image: url("../images/plus.svg");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    background-position:fixed;
    background-size:55px 55px;
    background-color:$red;

    @include transition(0.5s);
}
```

Comment: Remove the negative right margins

Comment: @Sevanteri removing the negative margins makes the last item move down  below the rest

Comment: @lbollu Change `border` to `outline` or remove the borders.

Comment: It's because you gave negative margin to your `.grid-item` class. Add `Box-sizing:border-box` to it's parent element or better use a CSS reset like normalize.css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess your server (or build process) is minifying the HTML (maybe with PageSpeed or similar module), thus removing spaces between the boxes, which your CSS relied on. You seem to use the negative margin to work around the spaces problem, but the real solution is: remove the spaces from your HTML and then you can also remove the negative margins from your CSS.

Comment: Thank you! This is the issue. I will ensure to go and remove my margins also.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `margin-right` and set `box-sizing` to `border-box`:

```
.grid-wrapper {
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  margin:0px auto;
}

.grid-wrapper img {
  width:99.8%;
  height:auto;
}

.grid-item {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width:20%;
  /*margin-right:-6px;*/
  margin-bottom:0px;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  border:1px solid #cfd0d1;
  border-top:0px solid #cfd0d1;   
  background-color:#ffffff;

  @media #{$l-desktop} {
    width:25%;
    /*margin-right:-6px;*/
  }

  @media #{$desktop} {
    width:33.3333%; /*33.2 will leave space on the right.*/
    /*margin-right:-5px;*/
  }

  @media #{$mobile} {
    width:50%;
    /*margin-right:-5px;*/
  }
}
```

Comment: Doing this doesn't allow the items to be on the same line. it knocks one down.. I think the border on each item is adding to the width

Comment: Adding `box-sizing: border-box` should resolve that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `.grid-item{box-sizing: border-box; margin-right: 0;}`

```
   @media (max-width: 1400px) {
.grid-item {margin-right:0;}
}  /* put margin-right 0 here */
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet. This is not an answer just a quick fix
 try

```
.grid-wrapper {
   width: 101%;
}
```